# Django - Why does context.get('request') return a None value?

Tags: django, python-3.x

Django version 1.8

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def current(context, url_name):
    print(context)
    print(context.get('request'))

    current_path = context.get('request').path

    return 'active' if current_path.startswith(url_name) else ''


>>> [{'True': True, 'False': False, 'None': None}, {'csrf_token': <django.utils.functional.lazy.<locals>.__proxy__ object at 0x7f61d288b860>, 'links': OrderedDict([('index', 'home'), ('products', 'prodotti'), ('contact_us', 'contattaci')])}, {'forloop': {'counter0': 2, 'revcounter': 1, 'revcounter0': 0, 'counter': 3, 'parentloop': {}, 'last': True, 'first': False}}, {'name': 'contattaci', 'key': 'contact_us'}]
>>> None
```

The response of the second print is actually None, but i can't figure out the reason. Seems like the 'request' object doesn't exist, or isn't available at all.

This is the interested part in the module settings.py.

```
    TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: The first print corresponds to `print(context)`?

Comment: @Gocht Ya, was pretty clear..

Comment: If it is, you should get an `AttributeError`, because a 'list' does not has `get` method. And as you can see, `print(context)` is printing a `list`.

Comment: <class 'django.template.context.RequestContext'>
I suppose the output is just a __repr__ of something to make it readable.

Comment: What does the view look like? Are you using the `render` shortcut?

Comment: Can you show your template where you are using the tag?

Comment: @Alasdair http://dpaste.com/0FRX20P/

Comment: How are you including that template? For example, with `{% include nav.html %}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request and other values from context processors are missing from the context.

The request is still available as an attribute on the `RequestContext`. You can access it with `context.request`.

Comment: The OP has the `request` context processor, so `request` should be in the context dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Context processors run immediately before the template is rendered, i.e. are not accessible from where you're running that code. Pass the context to a template and print {{ request }} somewhere and you will see the HttpRequest object.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/api/#

For what it's worth - if you're trying to get the request object, it's the first argument passed to pretty much every view. You can access it and share it there. If you're strictly trying to get access to it in a template, try accessing it like I mentioned above and see if you can get to it.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/views/

Comment: I'm fairly certain of this. You could test it pretty easily. Somebody please feel free to correct me if I'm mistaken here.

Comment: It's right, request is passed to template, so you can print it there.

Comment: What do you mean by passing the context?
return render(request, 'foo.html', {'request': request})
something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Complementing @Mothbawls answer, if you need pre_process the request or context_data, you could use a [request_process](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/middleware/#process_request) or a [process_template_response](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/middleware/#process_template_response) middleware.

Answer (score 0):

Also complementing @Mothbawls answers, for CBV's, I use the following Mixin to pass in the request to the template context:

```
class RequestMixin(object):
    """ Generic mixin to pass request data into context. """
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(RequestMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['request'] = self.request
        return context
```

Comment: It's not going to work, because i cannot access to the request object! That's the problem.

Comment: The `request` object is not passed in the `context` by default. The only way to pass the `request` object into `context` is to do so from within the Django View. I'm assuming your Django View has a `request` object...

Comment: If your Django View doesn't have a `request`, then there are other problems. And you may need to post your views.py and urls.py.

Comment: If you use the `request` context processor, then you don't need to explicitly pass request in the template context. This works for views that use a request context, including the admin, generic class based views and views that use the render shortcut.